# Not able to call WMI from threads in Python

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, wmi

I'm trying to use the [WMI](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/) library for a few very simple queries:

- Service state
- Number of processes running
- Free disk space

No problem so far, until I start introducing threads.

My first attempt had a class (Rules) deriving from `threading.Thread` and called another class (Check) which performed the WMI calls.

To overcome the threading issues, I used the `pythoncom` library to initialize and and uninitialize at the beginning and end of the WMI query. Here's what it looked like:

```
class Process(Check):

    def __init__(self, process_name, expected_instances=1):
        self.expected_instances = expected_instances
        self.process_name = process_name


    def run(self):
        import wmi, pythoncom
        pythoncom.CoInitialize()
        try:
            self.wmi_process = wmi.WMI().Win32_Process
            process_count = len(self.wmi_process(name=self.process_name))

            if process_count == self.expected_instances:
                return result.Success('Found {0} {1} processes'.format(process_count, self.process_name))
            else:
                return result.Failure('Found {0} {1} processes, expected {2}'.format(process_count, self.process_name, self.expected_instances))
        finally:
            pythoncom.CoUninitialize()
```

This worked, but would still result in the error `Win32 exception occurred releasing IUnknown` when the main process exited.

I took the advice given in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880723/win32-exception-occurred-releasing-iunknown-at-error-using-pylons-and-wmi), and moved the WMI querying to a separate class, which would have one instance that would be passed to the threads.

```
class WMIService:

    __lock = threading.Lock()

    def __init__(self):
        log.debug('Initializing WMI')
        pythoncom.CoInitialize()
        self.wmi = wmi.WMI()
        self.wmi_process = self.wmi.Win32_Process
        self.wmi_service = self.wmi.Win32_Service
        self.wmi_disk = self.wmi.Win32_LogicalDisk

    def get_process_count(self, process_name):
        with self.__lock:
            log.debug('Retrieving information for process "{0}"'.format(process_name))
            return len(self.wmi_process(name=process_name))
```

The thread lock has been created as a class variable, and to query the WMI, the lock has to be acquired first, ruling out parallel access (which I hoped would solve the issue).

However, this is the error Python spits out if I try to call the `get_process_count()` method from a thread. Again, running this in an interactive session works just fine.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\pyEnvs\pyWatch\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 1001, in _raw_query
    return self._namespace.ExecQuery (strQuery=wql, iFlags=flags)
  File "<COMObject winmgmts:>", line 3, in ExecQuery
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 282, in _ApplyTypes_
    result = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(*(dispid, LCID, wFlags, retType, argTypes) + args)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'SWbemServicesEx', None, None, 0, -2147221008), None)
…
```

All help would be very much appreciated, as both threading and WMI are a first for me. If I can't get this to work, the only alternative is to replace the WMI library with calls to the `WMIC` command, although I doubt that would benefit performance.

Comment: For the first approach, it seems you need to first import wmi in the main thread to avoid the exception.

Comment: @eryksun quite so, adding `import wmi` to the main thread solved the issue of an exception occurring at the end of execution. I don't quite understand why though; I'd be grateful if you could point me to the explanation of what I'm missing.